# python selenium can I use if else statement like try except for avoid error or interruption of code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I am using this try except statement:

```
try:
  address = i.find_element_by_css_selector('.businessCapsule--link')
  address = address.text
  print(address)
except:
  address = None
```

so my above code will set value of `address = None` if element not found. I tried to do this same things using if else statement  but it's not working and throwing error when element not found. Here is my code:

```
address = i.find_element_by_css_selector('.businessCapsule--link')
if address is not None:
    address = address.text
    print(address)
else:
   address = None
```

Why my if else statement not working like try except statement? Why it's can't set value of address none if element not found?

Answer (score 0):

The line `address = i.find_element_by_css_selector('.businessCapsule--link')` will raise an exception if the element isn't found. It does not return "None". There's no way around that, so it's a perfect use case for catching the exception in an `except` block. Why are you attempting to use if/else?

Keep the top code block, make sure you specify the exception and don't use a "[bare except](https://www.flake8rules.com/rules/E722.html)".

```py
try:
  address = i.find_element_by_css_selector('.businessCapsule--link')
  address = address.text
  print(address)
except NameOfSpecificExceptionHere:
  address = None
```

I'd suggest setting up your IDE such that you can just click on the method being called and see what it is doing. You'll see the exact line where the exception is being raised if you dig deep enough.